# Iterate through selected checkbox

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

I have a interactive grid with editing mode enabled which enables checkbox

I use APEX version : `20.x`

**Need :**

When I select multiple check box I need to iterate through the selected checkbox one by one and get details and store into variable

**My GUI**
[image: GUI]

**I am good with python ... below is the logic need to be written in apex way**

```
while i in IRreport  
do  
    if checkbox = true then

         fstname = IRreport(i)[firstname]
         lstname  = IRreport(i)[lastname]
         insert into emp values (fstname,lstname); 

    else
         null;
    end if;

done
```

**Expected Output : In my emp table**

```
Lastname  , Firstname 
King      , Stevens
Kochhar   , Neen
Partners  , karen
Hartstein , Michael
```

Comment: @Koen Lostrie : Can you provide your input for above posted question

Comment: I don't see an immediate answer to that - In an interactive grid the data is updated in the grid itself. You want a custom action that picks the selected rows and then executes some dml - not something I'm very familiar with.

Comment: @KoenLostrie : Any idea how to filter my selected checkbox ?

Comment: Not from the top of my head no. Check this blog https://srihariravva.blogspot.com/2019/02/interactive-grid-bulk-operation.html it might help. The IG Cookbook is also a good source for tips on IG. This isn't really a question for me